# i18n trac-плагина посредством Babel

Tags: python, i18n, trac, babel

Доброго времени суток.

Есть необходимость интернационализировать trac-плагин. Пытаюсь это сделать с использованием Babel. Пыхтя целый день над документацией с моим "техническим" английским, выяснил, что переводимые строки необходимо заключать в функцию `_()`, и иметь структуру каталогов подобную `<directory>/<locale>/LC_MESSAGES/<domain>.mo` (аналогично, собственно, использование стандартного `gettext` из коробки).

А вот что дальше делать, понять не могу. Может кто сталкивался с данным инструментом? Проблема заключается именно в правильном использовании Message Catalogs.

Спасибо.

P.S. Хорошо бы админы метку `babel` добавили =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фуф, ну вот, разобрался-таки! Ну вот что мешает разработчикам добавить в руководство пользователя несколько строчек по использованию данного инструмента?

В общем, смотрим ниже как же использовать свои Message Catalogs:

```
from babel.support import Translations
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
t = Translations.load(dirname=resource_filename(__name__, 'locale'), locales=['ru'], domain='messages')
t.install()
```

Вуаля, все помеченные `_()` строки переводятся на русский язык.